# Opacity on Surface background property

Tags: javascript, css, famo.us

The following gave me error

```
var textSurface = new Surface({
  content: 'Some text here',
  properties:{
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: rgba(0,0,0,0.7)
  }
});
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: rgba is not defined

My goal is to keep the text color with set opacity only on the background color. `rgba` works as a css function but it doesn't seem to work in surface's property. Can someone confirm and if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The background color needs to be a string.  What you have is an actual JavaScript function that is not defined, hence the error.

```
backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
```

Comment: Right...LOL What a dump mistake on my end.